# AJAX: Javascript function does not work after content is loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently, I am having problem where after i load my first content using ajax my javascript functiion is not working. I tried other solutions but most of them are in jquery format. Mine is in javascript format. I have tried to create a simple alert function to test whether the function is being called. But i ended up getting this error **`Uncaught ReferenceError: showArtistDetails is not defined`** Actually the function is already defined at the top of my head tag but still its showing undefined. Can I know are there any ways to solve this error.

This is the ajax code:

```
function showArtistDetails(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        alert("hi");
        document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        alert("hi1");

            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
                        alert("hi2");

            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("artist").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                            alert("hi3");

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getArtist.php?title="+str,true);
                    alert("hi4");

        xmlhttp.send();
                    alert("hi5");

    }
}
```

This is the php code:

```
    echo "<td onclick=\"showArtistDetails(this.value)\">" . $row['CDTitle'] . "</td>";
```

I really need someones help on this problem. Most of the users had the same problem with jquery function but mine is different. Thank you in advance. Helps are really appreciated.

Comment: Since this is purely a javascript issue, I would suggest editing your post to show the rendered html/js in a code block, it will help others to help you with you problem

Comment: Sorry you missunderstood, we do not need to see the php, it is a js issue. In your web browser, right click select view source and copy - paste the output into your question

Comment: i have copy paste the source code as you have said. But its not showing the latest code. its only showing the previous function code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem bug free. i din't find issue, check bellow code. 
Try to place  at bottom of page. 
And make sure you use type="text/javascript"

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Fanzine</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wholeThing">
        <div id="binder">
            <section id="content">
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <hgroup>
                            <h1 style="text-align:center; font-size: 20px;">Tip Top Fanzine</h1>
                        </hgroup>
                    </header>
                    <p> <!-- Content -->
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                        <select name="category" onchange="showMusic(this.value)"><option value='1'></option><option value='10'>Chamber</option><option value='11'>Classic Rock</option><option value='12'>Classical</option><option value='13'>Comedy</option><option value='14'>Contemporary Folk</option><option value='15'>Country</option><option value='16'>Cult</option><option value='17'>Death Metal</option><option value='18'>Easy Listening</option><option value='19'>Electronic</option><option value='2'>Acid Jazz</option><option value='20'>Electronica</option><option value='21'>Folk</option><option value='22'>Free Style</option><option value='23'>General Folk</option><option value='24'>General Rock</option><option value='25'>genre</option><option value='26'>Gothic</option><option value='27'>Jazz</option><option value='28'>Jungle/Drum 'N Bass</option><option value='29'>Keyboard</option><option value='3'>Alternative</option><option value='30'>Latin</option><option value='31'>Latin Rap</option><option value='32'>Louie</option><option value='33'>Medieval</option><option value='34'>misc</option><option value='35'>Miscellaneous</option><option value='36'>Mob Hits</option><option value='37'>New Age</option><option value='38'>New Wave</option><option value='39'>Oldies</option><option value='4'>Alternative Pop/Rock</option><option value='40'>Other</option><option value='41'>Pop</option><option value='42'>Pop/Rock</option><option value='43'>Progressive Folk</option><option value='44'>Psychedelic</option><option value='45'>Rap</option><option value='46'>Rap/R&B</option><option value='47'>Reggae</option><option value='48'>RnB</option><option value='49'>Rock</option><option value='5'>Ambient</option><option value='50'>Rock/Pop</option><option value='51'>RockNRoll</option><option value='52'>Roots Reggae</option><option value='53'>Soft Rock</option><option value='54'>Soul</option><option value='55'>Soundtrack</option><option value='56'>Techno</option><option value='57'>Traditional Folk</option><option value='58'>Traditional Pop</option><option value='59'>Trip-Hop</option><option value='6'>AvantGarde</option><option value='60'>Vocal</option><option value='61'>World</option><option value='62'>World Classical</option><option value='63'>Afro-Beat</option><option value='7'>Ballad</option><option value='8'>Bluegrass</option><option value='9'>Blues</option></select>
                    </div>                </p>
                    <div id="albums"></div>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function showMusic(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("albums").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getAlbums.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Script**

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Still its saying undefined function

Comment: make sure you have latest version of browser, java script must not be disable for browser..

Comment: no i am using the latest version of chrome.. the same code if tried at the first ajax content it works but at the second ajax content its not working

Comment: html, given by you is load directly, or  you load this html content in other page by using ajax ?

Comment: its still the same... the same undefined function

Comment: once try to execute, page in private browser in chrome by hit  "ctrl + shift + N"

Answer (score 0):

You say: "the function is already defined at the top of my head tag"

I only see one named function in the head tag: *showMusic(str)*

Where is *showArtistDetails* defined?

Comment: Now I see your php-snip. But I don't think you can inject new javascript-code into a html-page via ajax

Comment: What happens if you exchange 
`onclick=\"showArtistDetails(this.value)\"`
with
`onclick=\"alert(this)\"` ?

Comment: I am getting `[object HTMLTableCellElement]`

Comment: Ok. So one can actualy inject javascript code :-)
Then I have a suspision, that it might have somthing to do with the scope.
I still can't see where the ajax-call to the php-script is done from. Is it in the same html-file as where the *showArtistDetails*-function is defined?